# What "d' score" refers to?

Tags: terminology, cohens-d

I know this may be a very simple question, but I was reading a paper doing d' score from the results. In this paper, participants receive a rhythmic pattern twice, and then they get another rhythmic pattern which is either the same or different from the first two and they should indicate whether the third presentation is the same or different from the first two.
I searched on google and there are different things: "difference score", "deviation score", or "Cohen's D". I don't know if all of them are the same?! And if they are different which one is used by this paper.
I appreciate it a lot if you could explain it to me.
The paper is "see what I hear? Beat perception in auditory and visual rhythms" by "Jessica A. Grahn".

Answer (score 1):

It appears not to be a statistical concept, but rather a metric in the context of the study. Specifically, the caption to Figure 3 suggests it is a measurement of sensitivity to changes in the auditory sequence.

> The sensitivity to the presence of a deviant (as indexed by d’
> scores) for each rhythm type in each modality.